# Bubble Sort the number value either from (High to Low) or (Low to High)

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I'm getting a hard time figuring out on this one.
I have 2D array of strings which contain names and their age.
I want to sort it by using their age. I was able to sort the ages by converting to int but 
the problem is the names is not arranging according to its respective age. Can anyone help me?

```
String [][]data={
                 {"Jon", "17"},
                 {"Jim", "10"},
                 {"Tom", "15" }};
```

Expected output:
Jim 10
Tom 15
Jon 17

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: A sidenote - "2D arrays" are annoying to work with, you should create a simple class to represent a person.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to represent your data say `Person`. Now that class will define a way to be compared against other `Person` objects and that is done inside the `compareTo`.

Now when you call `Array.sort()` the method knows how to compare two distinct person objects (by their age in this case).

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person[] people = new Person[3];
        people[0] = new Person("John", 17);
        people[1] = new Person("Jim", 10);
        people[2] = new Person("Tom", 15);
        Arrays.sort(people);

        for(Person p : people)
            System.out.println(p.name + ", " + p.age);
    }
}

class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    public final String name;
    public final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return age - person.age;
    }
}
```

Output,

```
Jim, 10
Tom, 15
John, 17
```